# The native attribute can only be used with function definitions

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

What does the error message "the native attribute can only be used with function definitions" in the context of ActionScript 3 mean? I've tried googling for information but I haven't had any luck. The code I am trying to update (from here: https://github.com/jmhnilbog/Nilbog-Lib-AS2/blob/master/mx/mx/remoting/debug/NetDebug.as) is as follows:

```
import mx.remoting.debug.events.NetDebugTrace;
import mx.remoting.debug.GlobalLocalConnection;
import mx.remoting.debug.events.NetDebugError;
import mx.remoting.debug.NetDebugConfig;
import mx.remoting.debug.events.NetDebugFailedSendError;
import mx.remoting.debug.commands.GetConfig;
import mx.remoting.debug.events.NetDebugStatus;
import mx.remoting.debug.events.NetDebugTraceNetServices;

native class mx.remoting.debug.NetDebug extends Object
{
   public function NetDebug();
   private var _config:mx.remoting.debug.NetDebugConfig;
   private var _glc:mx.remoting.debug.GlobalLocalConnection;
   private var _ncs:Array;
   private var _nextNewId:Number;
   private function _trace(traceobj:Object):Void;
   private function _traceNetServices(who:String, severity:String, number:Number, message:String):Void;
   public function addNetConnection(nc:NetConnection):Number;
   public function getConfig():mx.remoting.debug.NetDebugConfig;
   static public function getNetDebug():mx.remoting.debug.NetDebug;
   static public function globalOnStatus(statusobj:Object):Void;
   static public function initialize():Boolean;
   static private var ndSingleton:mx.remoting.debug.NetDebug;
   public function onEvent(eventObj:Object):Boolean;
   public function onEventError(errorObj:Object):Boolean;
   public function onReceiveCommand(commandobj:Object):Void;
   public function onReceiveError(errorobj:Object):Void;
   public function removeNetConnection(nc:NetConnection):Void;
   public function requestNewConfig():Boolean;
   public function sendCommand(commandobj):Boolean;
   public function sendDebugEvent(eventobj:Object):Boolean;
   public function sendStatus(statusobj:Object):Boolean;
   static public function stripNCDEventToMinmal(ev:Object):Object;
   static public function trace(obj:Object):Void;
   static public function traceNetServices(who:String, severity:String, number:Number, message:String):Void;
   public function updateConfig(config:Object):Void;
   static var version:String;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes can't be `native`, only their functions.

The native keyword denotes that an AS3 function is a thin wrapper around *native* code (ie compiled assembly).

Comment: What I did after posting this was to change all of the function definitions to native (aside from that associated with the constructor) and remove the native modifier from the class. Is this correct?

Comment: According to Adobe: [Native] specifies that a function or method is implemented by Flash Player in native code. Flash Player uses the native keyword internally to declare functions and methods in the ActionScript application programming interface (API). **This keyword cannot be used in your own code.**. This discussion may be helpful: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/672331. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to include NetServices.as and NetDebug.as in my ActionScript 3 code. Unfortunately they seem to have taken these classes out of AS3, so I'm working backwards from some old AS2 code I found trying to add them in. The native class defined above was originally an extrinsic class.